# Combine flexibility + ism , how ? thanks

Tags: grammar, borrowing, compounds

I want to use the word flexibility in an "ism" form. I have two possible forms in mind but sure which one is better:

> 1. flexibilism
> 2. flexibiltyism

Which of the above forms is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: What sense do you intend to convey through this combination?

Comment: perhaps better suited to latin.SE

Comment: The underlying question for acceptance of neologisms - if this were one - though linguistically inclined, is still dependent on cultural constraints.

Answer (score 1):

In *The Transition to Flexibility* by Daniel C. Knudsen, Knudsen calls it flexibilism.

Knudsen states the following:

> "The terms "flexibilism" and "flexible accumulation" refer to flexible production along with its emerging social and political institutions" (pg. 2).

Comment: Thank you so much ! Flexibilism . I take it.